# How to collect volume per year for references type using json format?

Tags: r

Having a format from bibliographic references likes this:

```
@article{alvarez2015skillrank,
  title={Skillrank: Towards a hybrid method to assess quality and confidence of professional skills in social networks},
  author={{\'A}lvarez-Rodr{\'\i}guez, Jose Mar{\'\i}a and Colomo-Palacios, Ricardo and Stantchev, Vladimir},
  journal={Scientific Programming},
  volume={2015},
  pages={3},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Hindawi Publishing Corp.}
}

@inproceedings{arora2017supporting,
  title={Supporting collaborative software development in academic learning environment: A collaborative pair and quadruple programming based approach},
  author={Arora, Ritu and Goel, Sanjay and Mittal, RK},
  booktitle={2017 Tenth International Conference on Contemporary Computing (IC3)},
  pages={1--7},
  year={2017},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{bachrach2015human,
  title={Human judgments in hiring decisions based on online social network profiles},
  author={Bachrach, Yoram},
  booktitle={2015 IEEE International Conference on Data Science and Advanced Analytics (DSAA)},
  pages={1--10},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

How is it possible to produce a dataframe which have for every year the number of articles and conference per year.

Example out put

```
year, article, conference
2015,1,1,
2016,0,0
2017,0,1
```

Comment: Looks like a bibtex file - try searching around for "*R bibtex parser*" - there seem to be a few options out there for pre-existing packages that should be able to handle this - e.g.: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bib2df/vignettes/bib2df.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the RefManageR package read the file, `nathalie.bib` into R.  Then  convert it to a data frame, and perform the count specifying the variables to group by.

```
library(dplyr)
library(RefManageR)

"nathalie.bib" %>%
  ReadBib %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  count(bibtype, year)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  bibtype       year      n
  <chr>         <chr> <int>
1 Article       2015      1
2 InProceedings 2015      1
3 InProceedings 2017      1
```

### Tabular format

If `d` is the data frame of counts displayed above then this gives it as a 2d table:

```
d %>%
  xtabs(n ~ year + bibtype, .) %>% 
  addmargins(FUN = list(total = sum), quiet = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
       bibtype
year    Article InProceedings total
  2015        1             1     2
  2017        0             1     1
  total       1             2     3
```